# Speeding up the for-loop on Android

Tags: java, android

We need help with this for-loop from a third party library we're using. It's really slow and we want to help them with a solution but are struggling with this ourselves. Say we have two arrays:

```
ArrayList<String> values;
ArrayList<String> displayValues;
```

We want to add 10'000 values and displayValues to these. Currently the code looks like this:

```
void init() {
    int min = 0;
    int max = 10000;
    Calendar cal = pickerView.getInitialDate();
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -max/2);


    for(int i=0; i<=(max-min); i++){
        values.add(format.format(cal.getTime()));

        // Print "today" if date is today
        if(i == max/2){
            String todayString = Utils.printToday(pickerView.locale);
            String todayStringCapitalized = todayString .substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + todayString.substring(1);
            displayValues.add(todayStringCapitalized);
        }
        else displayValues.add(displayFormat.format(cal.getTime()).substring(3));
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    }

    picker.setDisplayedValues(displayValues.toArray(new String[0]));
}
```

It loops through 10'000 times and add a day at the time to both the displayValues and values list. The loop is really slow and uses between 200ms and 400ms when running on a device. Is there any way we can speed this up without looping through 10'000 times?

Comment: Try to find out, what part exactly is using up your time. A loop itself shouldn’t be the problem. Maybe first try to initialize your array lists with a predefined size e.g. `ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(10000);`. You can use the Android Studio Profiler (https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler) to check what calls are time intensive.

Comment: Also, because you know the count of elements in the array from the start, consider using a basic Array instead of an ArrayList. This should get you a meaningful performance bump too.  `String[] values = new String[10000];`. That way the memory allocation for the array is done in before and not each time when a new value is added.

Comment: Ideas: set the initial capacity of your `ArrayLists`; only call `cal.getTime()` once per loop; change `displayFormat` so you don't have to remove the first 3 chars via `substring`. Don't think these are going to make a huge difference though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it's just calendar days, you can get all CS purist and make it a linkedList instead of being array based.  Keep a reference to head, tail, and today. Then each day just modify the today value (now yesterday, but still stored in "today" reference) to a normal day format, set the next value (today.next(), representing the new calendar today) to the format you need, set your today reference to today.next() (so that it now accurately reflects what is actually today), remove the first value, and add a new day to the end.  **Bam, constant time.**  The beauty of this solution is that even if your list is a billion items long, it'll take the same amount of time (though Android will probably kill your app for using too much memory at that point).

I would recommend extending Java's LinkedList class and having your list object store a reference to today and then just having an increment day method that does all the work of changing it.

https://www.callicoder.com/java-linkedlist/

But since you asked on optimizing your for loop, a few thoughts.

First of all, initialize your ArrayLists to 10,000 items initially.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(10000);
```

Might as well not make your loop deal with doubling and copying things to it over and over.

Second, statements like the following are slowing you down:

```
String todayString = Utils.printToday(pickerView.locale);
String todayStringCapitalized = todayString .substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + todayString.substring(1);
```

This is actually creating 5 strings because strings are immutable in java.  THis unnecessary object creation overhead probably adds up over 10k iterations.  Whenever you're doing this string stuff you can do something like this instead:

```
StringBuilder todayStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(Utils.printToday(pickerView.locale));
todayStringBuilder.setCharAt(0, Character.toUpperCase(todayStringBuilder.charAt(0)));
displayValues.Add(todayStringBUilder.toString());
```

Third, the following line:

```
picker.setDisplayedValues(displayValues.toArray(new String[0]));
```

Just use:

```
picker.setDisplayedValues(displayValues.toArray());
```

No reason to create a 0 length array to store 10,000 values.

Also wrap all of this up in an AsyncTask so it doesn't run on the UI thread:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Generally what's adding up is all the string stuff.  If you can simplify your calendar formatter to only create one string for each day instead of having to call substring every time, it'll go faster.